# Rspec stubing view for anonymous controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test a method on the application controller that will be used as a before filter. To do this I have setup an anonymous controller in my test with the before filter applied to ensure that it functions correctly.

The test currently looks like this:

```
describe ApplicationController do
  controller do
    before_filter :authenticated

    def index      
    end
  end

  describe "user authenticated" do
    let(:session_id){"session_id"}
    let(:user){OpenStruct.new(:email => "pythonandchips@gmail.com", :name => "Colin Gemmell")}

    before do
      request.cookies[:session_id] = session_id
      UserSession.stub!(:find).with(session_id).and_return(user)
      get :index
    end

    it { should assign_to(:user){user} }

  end
end
```

And the application controller is like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def authenticated
    @user = nil
  end
end
```

My problem is when ever I run the test I'm getting the following error

```
1) ApplicationController user authenticated 
   Failure/Error: get :index
   ActionView::MissingTemplate:
     Missing template stub_resources/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :haml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::PathSetDelegatorResolver:0x984f310>"
```

According to the docs the view is not [rendered when running controller tests](http://rspec.info/rails/writing/controllers.html) however this points to no stub existing for this action (which is understandable as the view doesn't exist)

Anyone have a clue how to solve this problem or stub the view out.

Cheers
Colin G

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Couldn't you get round this by putting:

```
render :nothing => true
```

inside the `#index` action?

Comment: `head :ok` for Rails 5

Answer (score 4):

A better way to do this is to create a dummy views directory. I wouldn't use spec/views, as that is actually for valid view tests. Instead, create this directory structure:

```
spec/test_views/anonymous
     index.html.erb
     ... and any other anonymous controller templates you happen to need ...
```

index.html.erb can be empty, as noted, since rspec2 is only checking for existence, not for content.

Then in your application.rb initializer, place this line:

```
# add a view directory for the anonymous controller tests
config.paths['app/views'] << "spec/test_views" if Rails.env.test?
```

Note: I tried putting that line in test.rb, for some reason doesn't seem to work there.

Answer (score 3):

Unless things changed from [this blog post](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/06/28/view-isolation-in-rspec-rails-2/), RSpec 2 needs a view template file for controller specs to work. The file itself is not rendered (unless you add `render_views`), so the contents don't matter -- in fact you can simply add an empty file with `touch index.html.erb`.

Comment: I had to add a dummy templates in "app/views/anonymous/index.html.erb". I couldn't figure out how to put the dummy views off under spec/views.

Comment: You have it right -- the empty template goes in `app/views`, not `spec/views`, which makes sense, since that is where Rails looks for it.

Comment: you can tell it to look for the dummy views under spec/views if you add the following line to application.rb: `    # add a view directory for the anonymous controller tests
    `config.paths['app/views'] << "spec/views" if Rails.env.test?`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at this for Rails 5+, putting `head :ok` in the index action is the right answer, as indicated by [marc_ferna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121852/marc-ferna) in a comment under another answer.

e.g.

```
controller do
    before_filter :authenticated

    def index      
      head :ok
    end
  end
```